# Css фильтр - отбеливание

Tags: css

Есть черные иконки. 
Хочу при нажатии, чтобы они становились белыми. 
Есть ли какие-то фильтры в css для этого?

Answer (score 1):

Работает только в webkit-браузерах.

```
img {
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
}
```

**[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/k7WzL/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Для этого у Вас должны быть 2 варианта картинок - черная и белая.
Почитайте о спрайтах.

Comment: это да. Не охота было вручную просто каждую картинку высветлять